# GRT Fixed Responsive Menu - jQuery Plugin - problem with closing menu (after click the link)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a problem with closing my mobile menu - which I implemented on my website using the jQuery plugin: https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Sticky-Mobile-Navigation-GRT-Responsive-Menu.html.

When I click on the links inside the menu it is still open - it's going to the section but the menu isn't close.
I need help with what JS function to use to be able to automatically close the menu after clicking the appropriate link.

Below my code:

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.grtmobile = function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('.grt-mobile-button').on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("grt-mobile-button-open");
            $("ul.grt-menu").toggleClass("open-grt-menu ");
        });
    }
}})( jQuery );
```

I would be grateful for any help what I should add to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem after applying the code below - now it works but sometimes the "burger" disappears and not always the icon returns to the initial state

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.grtmobile = function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('.grt-mobile-button').on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("grt-mobile-button-open");
            $("ul.grt-menu").toggleClass("open-grt-menu ");
        });
        $('a').on('click', function(){
            $('.grt-mobile-button').parent().removeClass("grt-mobile-button-open");
            $("ul.grt-menu").removeClass("open-grt-menu");
          });
    }
}
```

})( jQuery )